# WIN10 "Unknown publisher" UAC-warning with program compiled with MinGW and "patch" in name

Tags: mingw, patch, uac

I actually found a solution, but the problem is so odd I want to tell nevertheless.

On Win10 I compiled a little program once with MinGW and VS2012. The VS2012-version worked without issues, but the MinGW-version popped up an UAC warning  "Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your PC?".

Of course I searched the web, but none of the solutions worked.
Even Explorer shows the UAC-shield in the icon of the exe-file.

I finally discovered that if I rename the exe-file the problem disappears.

If the exe-filename contains the substring "patch" (the original filename was "svgpatcher.exe") the UAC-box will come. Without the "patch" even the UAC-shield in the icon disappears immediately.

So Win10 issues warnings depending on the filename!

If you can reproduce - do you have other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Just found this:
http://irq5.io/2011/06/26/gnu-patch-and-windows-uac/

Comment: and this:
https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/156
and:
http://math.nist.gov/oommf/software-patchsets/patch_on_Windows7.html